# Accepting Android licenses using Flutter without manual confirmation

Tags: android, bash, flutter, shell, zsh

I'm working on creating a shell script for setting up a machine as a CI/CD runner. We are going to build android APKs with flutter using this CI pipeline. In order to complete the initial runner setup, I need to install Android SDKs, Flutter CLI, etc. In that, I need to accept android licenses using this command:

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

In that, a prompt is appeared to type 'y' as confirmation. I know the licenses are to be read and accepted. But, as I'm writing a shell program, is there a way to bypass the manual confirmation?

In Linux, we use -y to avoid prompt during package installation. Similarly, is there a way to avoid manual confirmation?

Other information:

1. OS that I'm going to run this: MacOS
2. Terminal: zsh
3. Shell script: #!/bin/bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yes` outputs `y` forever:

```sh
yes | flutter doctor --android-licenses
```